# Submit button works when mandatory fields are empty?

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

I have a form with 20 fields. In this there are 10 mandatory fields. When I click submit button, the form shows only a red border for mandatory input fields and doesn't show error message. And also the submit works and hit the server.

```
input.submitted.ng-invalid
{
  border:1px solid #f00;
}
form.submitted .ng-invalid
{
border:1px solid #f00;
}
input.ng-touched.ng-invalid {
    border-color:red;
}
   input.ng-touched.ng-valid {
border-color:green;
  } 

this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
      Logo: [null, [Validators.required]], TournamentType: [null, Validators.required],
      TournamentName: [null, Validators.required], TournamentStartDate: [null, [Validators.required]],
      TournamentEndDate: [null, [Validators.required]], StarStatus: [null, [Validators.required]],
      EntryStartDate: [null, [Validators.required]], EntryEndDate: [null, [Validators.required]],
      Venue: [null, [Validators.required]], Address: [null, [Validators.required]],
      enfee: [null, [Validators.required]], PlayersCategory: [null, [Validators.required]],
      latitude: [null, [Validators.required]], longitude: [null, [Validators.required]]
    });
```

My HTML:

```
                <div class="form-group" [formGroup]="form">
                        <label class="lable label-default">Logo<span style="color: red">*</span></label><br>
                        <img [src]='imageURl' style='width:160px;height:140px;'>
                        <input type="file" id='Logo' formControlName="Logo"  name="Logo"  style="margin-top:10px" accept="image/*"
                        (change)="handleFileInput($event)"
                        [ngClass]="{'form-submitted': formSubmitted}" [(ngModel)]='tourDetails.Logo' required />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group" [formGroup]="form">
                        <label class="label label-default" for="tour-type">Tournament Type<span style="color: red">*</span></label>
                        <select id="TournamentType" formControlName="TournamentType" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="tourDetails.TournamentType"
                            name='TournamentType'  [ngClass]="{'form-submitted': formSubmitted}"
                             required>
                            <option value='' selected>Select</option>
                            <option *ngFor="let TT of tourType" value={{TT.value}}>{{TT.name}}</option>
                        </select>
                </div>  

                <div class="form-group" [formGroup]="form">
                    <label class="lable label-default">Tournament Name<span style="color: red">*</span></label>
                    <input id="TournamentName" class="form-control" name='TournamentName' formControlName="TournamentName"
                     [(ngModel)]='tourDetails.TournamentName'  [ngClass]="{'form-submitted': formSubmitted}"
                     required />
                </div>

                <div class="form-group inputWithIcon" [formGroup]="form">
                    <label class="lable label-default">Tournament Start Date<span style="color: red">*</span></label>
                    <input class="form-control input-wrapper " bsDatepicker type="text" name='TournamentStartDate'
                        [(ngModel)]="tourDetails.TournamentStartDate" autocomplete='off' [bsConfig]="{ dateInputFormat: 'DD-MM-YYYY' }"
                        [outsideClick]="true" [maxDate]='tourDetails.TournamentEndDate'
                          formControlName="TournamentStartDate" [ngClass]="{'form-submitted': formSubmitted}" required> 
                </div>

                <div class="form-group inputWithIcon" [formGroup]="form">
                    <label class="lable label-default">Tournament End Date<span style="color: red">*</span></label>
                    <input class="form-control input-wrapper" bsDatepicker type="text" name='TournamentEndDate'
                        [(ngModel)]="tourDetails.TournamentEndDate"  autocomplete='off' [bsConfig]="{ dateInputFormat: 'DD-MM-YYYY' }"
                        [outsideClick]="true" [minDate]='tourDetails.TournamentStartDate'
                         formControlName="TournamentEndDate" [ngClass]="{'form-submitted': formSubmitted}" required>
                </div>
```

The Result I want:
When I click submit button it won't work when mandatory fields are empty. At the same time mandatory input fields shows error message of "Please fill this required field" with red border of input fields.

Comment: can you please show me the html?

Comment: I add my html code. Please check

Comment: You should add the HTML code including the **form** tag including the **submit** button. This way others will understand how you have declared your entire form. Adding all required/optional fields aren't of any use here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need put some like (*)

```
<div *ngIf="form.get('Logo').invalid && form.get('Logo').touched">Required</div>
```

And in submit function

```
submit()
{
    if (this.form.invalid)
        this.form.markAsUntouched()
    else
    {
         ...the form is valid...
    }
}
```

(*) You can also make a component

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-error',
  template: `
    <small class="form-text text-danger" *ngIf="isInvalid" >
       <ng-content></ng-content>
    </small>
`
})
export class ErrorComponent {

  @Input('controlName') controlName: string;
  @Input('error') error: string

  control: FormControl
  visible: boolean = false;

  get isInvalid() {
    const control = this.form.form.get(this.controlName);
    return control.touched && control.invalid && 
        (this.error ? control.errors[this.error] : true);
  }
  constructor(@Optional() @Host() private form: FormGroupDirective) { }
```

And use like

```
<app-error controlName="Logo">Logo required.</app-error>

<!---or if you has severals errors-->
<!-- imagine a control email with [Validators.required,Validators.email] -->

<app-error controlName="email" error="required">Email required.</app-error>
<app-error controlName="email" error="email">Email invalid.</app-error>
```

Comment: First div code works well. It shows error message. But after i fill the required fields the error message doesn't gone.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="form-group inputWithIcon" [formGroup]="form">
    <label class="lable label-default">Tournament End Date<span style="color: red">*</span></label>
    <input class="form-control input-wrapper" bsDatepicker type="text" name='TournamentEndDate'
        [(ngModel)]="tourDetails.TournamentEndDate"  autocomplete='off' [bsConfig]="{ dateInputFormat: 'DD-MM-YYYY' }"
        [outsideClick]="true" [minDate]='tourDetails.TournamentStartDate'
         formControlName="TournamentEndDate" [ngClass]="{'form-submitted': formSubmitted}" required>
    <span *ngIf="form.get('TournamentEndDate').hasError('required')">Please fill this required field
    </span>

    </div>
```